# Having issues with charset in my blazor project

Tags: blazor

I'm starting to work with blazor, with one demo project, and Im having a problem with the charset, its not working, maybe it's not implemented where it is needed, I don't really know.
So I have the charset implemented in the `index.html`, a html file inside the wwwroot, and in my `Index.razor` component. In my `Index.razor` Im calling other component only with body elements, where are the words that need accents.

The code that I have in index.html (I don't really know what this code does, it came with the demo):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="Guild Project"/>
    <title>Mission Control</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <script src="localStorage.js"></script>
    <link href="_content/RazorComponentsMaterialDesign/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="_content/RazorComponentsMaterialDesign/script.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/RazorComponentsMaterialDesign/lib/material-components-web.js"></script>
    <link href="css/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.0.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.0.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px">

    <app>
        <!-- "Loading" spinner -->
        <div role="progressbar" class="mdc-linear-progress mdc-linear-progress--indeterminate">
            <div class="mdc-linear-progress__buffer"></div>
            <div class="mdc-linear-progress__bar mdc-linear-progress__primary-bar"><span class="mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner"></span></div>
            <div class="mdc-linear-progress__bar mdc-linear-progress__secondary-bar"><span class="mdc-linear-progress__bar-inner"></span></div>
        </div>
    </app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/PinMapLibrary/PinMap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Index.razor code:

```
@page "/"
@using MissionControl.Client.Components;

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="layout">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <Sidebar/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here Im calling the component `Sidebar` where I have the words that need accents.

Sidebar code:

```
<p>Permissões</p>
```

As you can see Im implementing the charset in the index.html and in the Index.razor but its not working. You can see that in the image bellow.

[image: example]

I think I put all the information that you need to know about this issue but if you have some doubts just leave a comment. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: `Index.razor` should not contain <html> , <head> or <body> tags. That certainly isn't helping.

Comment: No repro. I dropped `<p>Permissões</p>` on a page and it works correctly.

Comment: Create a [mcve]. Start with a new standard template and make the  minimal changes to demonstrate the problem. Post all steps here, along with all relevant version numbers.

Comment: I just deleted <html>, <head> and <body> tags but still with same issue. I just finished testing and the problem is the calling the component. So if I put that word in my Index.razor it's ok but in my Sidebar component is not working.

Comment: I copied it to a component: Still no repro.

Comment: Make sure you try it in different Browsers.

Comment: So I created a new blazor project. I added my index.html to wwwroot. After that I had the default components (Pages file -> Index.razor, Counter.razor...). I added the `<p> Olá </p> to my Index.razor page and works fine. After I added `<Counter/>` to my Index.razor and in Counter.razor I just added `<p>Olá</p>` and the that "Olá" didn't worked.

Comment: [example](https://i.imgur.com/6ReSRwd.png)

As you can see here is the default project and the issue. Yes I tried with firefox and chrome and same result.

Comment: Why did you "added my index.html to wwwroot" ?  That shouldn't be necessary. Also, which template?

Comment: I created a ASP.NET Core Web Application, put the name, I chose Blazor Server App and there is the template.

Comment: Then you should have a `_Host.cshtml`,  not an `index.html`. Remove that `index.html` again.

Comment: My net went off sorry for the delay. Deleted it and I see that _Host have the charset implemented but same issue.

Comment: Did you try to save *Index.razor* with UTF8 enconding ?

Comment: Well, no clue here then.  Consider reweritng your question with the minimal steps. When you see the error, use the "View Source"  option in your browser and post the HTML..

Comment: @aguafrommars no I didn't.

Comment: @HenkHolterman So If you call Counter with `<p>Olá</p>` its fine for you???

Comment: in VS select *Index.razor*, then File -> Save Index.razor As. Click on down arrow beside the Save button. Select Save with Enconding. And Select Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001

Comment: Did you try to do the same with the Sidebar.razor ? Basicaly, save all with utf-8 enconding

Comment: @aguafrommars Omg finally. Thank you so so much!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save all your source code with UTF-8 encoding:

In Visual Studio

- select a file
- click File -> Save {the file} As...
- click the down arrow on save button [image]
- click **Save with Enconding...**
- select **Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001** in Encoding
- click OK

To configure VS to save as Unicode per default :

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Documents
Check **Save documents as Unicode when data cannot be saved in codepage**