# razor page (blazor) is encoding the characters

Tags: c#, .net, razor, blazor, razor-pages

I have a little website and when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on the website the UTF-8 characters are not being printed correctly.

For example if I try to print `programación` it prints `programaci&#xF3;n`

This is happening only when I print the value of a variable, it does not happen when I hardcode the text.

For example, `<div>@variable</div>` prints the content with the encoded values like `programaci&#xF3;n`. But the value itself, using the inspector is `programación`.

But if in the following line I write  `<div>programación</div>` it prints it correctly.

I tried to use [httputlity.htmldecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=net-5.0) but I got the same result.

I also tried the `meta charset=UTF-8` and I saved the `.razor` file as UTF. Like it is specified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57673138/having-issues-with-charset-in-my-blazor-project) but none of those worked.

Is there any way of printing those characters correctly?

I'm using .NET5 if that matters.

Comment: Which Browser ?  (No repro).

Comment: I tried in firefox, Chrome and edge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Razor encodes all non-ASCII characters, i.e. those outside of the [Basic Latin range](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf). If you want other ranges to be left alone, you need to configure that. You do so in the `ConfigureServices` method by specifying the ranges that Razor should **not** encode. The character you are having problems with is in the Latin-1 Supplement range, so you include that:

```
services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(
        UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin,
        UnicodeRanges.Latin1Supplement);
});
```

Note that whatever you set here will *override* the default settings, which is why you also need to include the `UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin` range. If you are unsure which character sets you should include, you can check here: http://www.unicode.org/charts/. Alternatively, you can simply specify `UnicodeRanges.All`.