# Blazor PageTitle with cyrillic string

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a `Blazor Server` app with render-mode `Server-Prerendered`.

Trying to pass cyrillic value to `<PageTitle>`

```
@page "/expert/{advisorId:int}"

<PageTitle>@Title</PageTitle>

@code {
    
    [Parameter]
    public int advisorId { get; set; }
    
    public string Title { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Title = "Кириллица";
    }

}
```

After run, the html contains:

```
<title>&#x41A;&#x438;&#x440;&#x438;&#x43B;&#x43B;&#x438;&#x446;&#x430;</title>
```

Expected value:

```
<title>Кириллица</title>
```

What is wrong with encoding and how to force it to use utf-8?

My html contains encoding meta tag with utf-8 value, but that can't be the problem.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68780976/20339875

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to maciek, for pointing me to the right direction.

By default, Razor encodes all non-ASCII characters. So wee need to configure:

```
builder.Services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(
        UnicodeRanges.All
        );
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68780976/20339875